# Are thunder and lightning necessary for any organisms?

Tags: ecology, growth

Comparatively irregular events such as forest fires are necessary for some plants to grow [(see here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_ecology).

But do any plant or animal species have similar dependence on thunder and/or lightning?

Comment: Lightning is more or less the only non-human cause of forest fires

Comment: @C_Z_ Ah, yes. That was not an intended connection, even though it is obvious now that you point it out. I was more thinking of direct effects of the immense light and sound…

Comment: do you mean for reproductive purposes? Or just in general?

Comment: @C_Z_ +1 for trees

Comment: @C_Z_ What about dry fires in summer/dry season? They happen very frequently. Are they _always_ started by people (genuinely curious)?

Comment: @James The only way for those fires to start in the dry season is with a spark. As far as I know, lightning is the only non-human source of a spark

Comment: @C_Z I disagree, volcanic action is also known to cause natural fires. Other sources of literature even suggest rubbing of some reactive rock materia can cause these sparks

Comment: I think it is higly unlikely that there are species that *directly* depend upon lighting. Lighting strikes occur to infrequently and random to be of any use to an organism from energetic point of view.

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh Generally, was my thought. I realise this easily becomes open ended. But every necessary aspect of an organism's life cycle is reproductive in some way, maybe?

Answer (score 7):

Lightning results in nitrogen fixation ([Draphco et al., 1967](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0004-6981(83)90420-1); [Hill et al., 1980](http://dx.doi.org/10.1175/1520-0469(1980)037%3C0179:ANFBL%3E2.0.CO;2)). It is one of the main abiotic nitrogen fixation mechanisms. As you would know very well, nitrogen fixation is important for all organisms.

Comment: This is very good, but if there are other sources of nitrogen fixation, organisms are not really dependent on this source of it?

Comment: @trmdttr there are some organisms (mostly micro-organisms) that can fix nitrogen on their own.

Comment: So basically, all other organisms that cannot fix nitrogen themselves are dependent on lightning? Or do they use the fixed nitrogen from those microorganisms?

Comment: @trmdttr they can depend on the other organisms that fix nitrogen as well as use the nitrogen fixed by the lightning. I believe initial lifeforms consumed the abiotically fixed nitrogen; subsequently some evolved to fix nitrogen themselves.

Comment: So, this answer doesn't really catch a *necessary* reliance on thunder or lightning for any specific organism? More a need for fixated nitrogen of which the majority comes from that source (but also from others)?

Comment: @trmdttr the necessity will depend on many bio-geographical factors.